# sybase odbc driver for windows

Tags: sql-server, odbc, sybase, sap-ase

We need to access SAP ASE (Sybase) data from a SQL Server 2016 hosted on Windows. Could not able to find Sybase ODBC driver download link from an SAP site. All i see is from third party vendors with trial version. How and where can i get that? Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not sure what SAP link you're referring to, but if you go to this [SAP download link](https://developers.sap.com/trials-downloads.html) and search the page for `Adaptive Server Enterprise` you'll find several links for the `ASE SDK`.

**NOTE:** The `ASE SDK` contains several drivers including the `SAP ASE ODBC Driver`.

Click on the appropriate link, provide the obligatory 'registration' details and you're provided with a copy of the `ASE SDK` package.

While the page does mention trial downloads, I've never found the `ASE SDK` to be limited by any licensing requirements.